# Mercurial: TortoiseHg's "guess rename" from the commandline?

Tags: mercurial, macos, rename

Is there any hg functionality to mimic the "guess renames" command of TortoiseHG?

I really dig this one, however I am currently using MacOS and have [Murky](http://bitbucket.org/snej/murky/wiki/Home) or the commandline interface available.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can do

```
hg addremove --similarity <percent>
```

Type hg help addremove for details.

Comment: omfgz that's the best thing I saw in version control systems ever!!

Comment: this is not identical to `thg guess` because it adds all untracked files, whereas TortoiseHg only moves files that were already in the repository.